# Make only one column editable

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

My goal is to make a grid where only the checkbox (`IsActive`) is editable and it should be editable without having to press an edit button. 
I would like for the checkbox to be bound to the model, instead of making a manual checkbox and then handle changes myself.

The result should look somewhat like this: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/headerfootertemplates

**Model**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(column =>
        {
            column.Bound(x => x.Id);
            column.Bound(x => x.Name);
            column.Bound(x => x.IsActive)
                  .HeaderTemplate(@<text>@Html.CheckBox("checkAll")</text>);
        })
    .EnableCustomBinding(true)
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Server().Select("Index", "Stuff"))
    .Render();
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Template` seems like the only option.

I switched to Ajax binding so I'm using `ClientTemplate`

```
column.Bound(x => x.IsActive)
      .ClientTemplate("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkedRecords\" value=\"<#= Id #>\" <#= IsActive ? \"checked='checked'\" : '' #> />")
      .HeaderTemplate(@<text>@Html.CheckBox("checkAll")</text>);
```

Now I just need to figure out how bind a checkbox click to a `command.Update()`.

Comment: Question regarding the update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616547/bind-clienttemplate-checkbox-click-to-command-update